# How to make an animation from files .dat contained in a folder

Tags: python

I have a folder with 98 .dat files and they are stellar spectra.

I would like to make an animation of certain elements line, such as Hydrogen, Helium and so on, contained in each spectrum. In this way, I think to have a better and clear situation of how elements behave in the whole set of spectra. I hope I've been clear enough!!

Does any of you have an idea on what should I do? If you had some visual examples, I would really appreciate.

I have no idea on how to recall the 98 files and, hence, how to make the animation.

Thanks a lot ❤️❤️

Comment: Hi Remo, it really depends on the data type of the spectra. You can make animations with different python libraries, for example using matplotlib there's an extension for it. If you show code how you load and plot one file, we can help you.

Comment: Hi Johannes, thanks a lot. I wish I could show the code but there's some sort of error that says......no possible to publish. Let me try again

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pandas as pd

def update(frame):
    plt.clf() 
    data= np.loadtxt(f'data_file_{frame}.dat') 
    x=data[:,0]
    y=data[:,1]
    plt.plot(data['x'], data['y'])
    plt.title(f'Frame {frame}')

num_frames = 5
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
animation = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=num_frames, interval=1000)
plt.show()

Comment: Johannes, I did it!!!!

Comment: Great! If you post the solution as a reply to your question, you can help others with the same problem :)